# nginx won't stop/restart failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

Versions:
This is a fresh turn up of a Ubuntu 14.04
NGINX 1.4.6

Summary:
issuing service nginx stop, does not stop the server, issuing nginx restart provides a fail! with an error of already in use.

Details:
I believe this is an issue with my vhosts, if i comment out the include for sites-enabled in the nginx.conf, it all behaves properly. I have read multiple sites stating about ipv6only and ipv4, but that appears to be fine, as this is the out of the box default

Apache is not installed, nginx is the only server.

Debugging:

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

lsof -i :80

COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   1208     root    7u  IPv4  10246      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1208     root    8u  IPv6  10247      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1209 www-data    7u  IPv4  10246      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1209 www-data    8u  IPv6  10247      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1210 www-data    7u  IPv4  10246      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1210 www-data    8u  IPv6  10247      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

service nginx stop

lsof -i :80

COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   1208     root    7u  IPv4  10246      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1208     root    8u  IPv6  10247      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1209 www-data    7u  IPv4  10246      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1209 www-data    8u  IPv6  10247      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1210 www-data    7u  IPv4  10246      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1210 www-data    8u  IPv6  10247      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx
 ...fail!
```

error-log:

```
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/05/14 14:58:48 [emerg] 14620#0: still could not bind()
```

Conf Files:
nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 2;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 5M;
    client_body_buffer_size 256k;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors off;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-available/default

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;

    #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on; # listen for IPv6 only traffic on IPv6 sockets
    #listen 80; # listen also for IPv4 traffic on "regular" IPv4 sockets

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```